# EmberJS - How to update object in an array

Tags: ember.js

Interesting, i don't know how to update object in an array.

see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbERr/13/)

i am getting this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'
```

i tried in many ways.

```
target.id = "Degree";
Ember.set('target.id', 'degree');
```

nothing helps.

Code i tried.

```
App.Config = [{id: "Gender"}, {id: "Martial Status"}];

var target = App.Config.findProperty("id", "Gender");

target.set("id", "Degree"); //see error in console.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your App.Config is just an array of plain javascript objects, not Ember objects, so it doesn't know what `set` is. To fix, we need to create an array of Ember objects:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Config = [
  Ember.Object.create({id: "Gender"}), 
  Ember.Object.create({id: "Martial Status"})
];

var target = App.Config.findProperty("id", "Gender");
console.log(target.get('id'));
target.set("id", "Degree"); //see updated values in console.
console.log(target.get('id'));
```

Working example http://jsbin.com/aqaber/1/edit